# Performance tuning: comparing two tables using Sets or data frame : Getting final message as "Killed"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, set

I have few tables , tables will be in different databases and below is sample comparison i am trying

```
EmplTbl = cur.execute("select A , B , C from EmployeeTable where EmplName in ('A','B')") 
emp_entries = set(cur)

DeptTbl = cur.execute("select A , B , C from DeptTable") 
dept_entries = set(cur) 

print(emp_entries.difference(dept_entries))
```

In this example i have provided only 3 columns for comparison. But in my case i have 30- 40 columns. 
when i am trying to do a difference between sets  or using 'for' loop or dataframe join comparison-- script is running very slow and i am getting final message as "Killed"

In the below code i am trying to do an inner join to get exact match

```
EmplTbl = cur.execute("select A , B , C from EmployeeTable where EmplName in ('A','B')") 
emp_entries = set(cur)

DeptTbl = cur.execute("select A , B , C from DeptTable") 

for DeptTbl in cur:
    if emp_entries in DeptTbl:
        print(emp_entries)
```

Volume of records: i may have up to 10million

Is there any way i can increase my performance make it to run fast. I have linux server with 4 node configuration. 
Please suggest

Comment: I don't understand the second code sample.  You're looping over the items in `dept_entries`, so obviously those items are present in `dept_entries`.  That `if` statement will _always_ be true.  Surely you didn't intend that.

Comment: @JohnGordon.. Thanks a lot for the reply.First way i am doing comparison with Sets and second way i am applying comparison using for loop

Comment: But it's a useless comparison, isn't it?  You're essentially saying "For each coin in my pocket, is that coin in my pocket?"  Well, yes, of course it is.

Comment: @JohnGordon.. Yes john , first case i need to do comparison like ( A minus B ) and second i am trying to do capture exact match records. I have edited the question

Comment: @JohnGordon. sorry for confusion..

Comment: @JohnGordon.. To add one more point. I have tables in different databases so thats why i can do the comparison using sql. i am trying to compare them into Sets or dataframes and performing comparison between them.

Comment: So can we consider this as the question of python rather than oracle database?

Comment: @Tejash.. Yes i am trying to capture data from two different tables into List or sets and comparison is done in python ( i cant do in database level)

Comment: @ Can someone suggest me with any solution

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use query for difference:

```
Select col1, col2, col3 from table 1
Minus
Select col1, col2, col3 from table2;
```

-- or --

```
Select col1, col2, col3 from table1 t1
Where exists 
(Select 1 from table2 t2
Where t1.col1 = t2.col1
And t1.col2 = t2.col2
And t1.col3 = t2.col3)
```

Cheers!!

Comment: @ I am trying to achieve this comparison using Sets , as i have tables in different databases.

Comment: So can we consider this as the question of python rather than oracle database?

Comment: Yes i am trying to capture data from two different tables into List or sets and comparison is done in python ( i cant do in database level)

Comment: @Can you help me with any suggestion

Comment: I am not python expert. I know database only :(